# Wine32 conflicts with gnome control center

Tags: wine, gnome-control-center

I tried install wine32 on my ubuntu 22.04 it setting option disappeared. I reinstall gnome-control-center with colord and libgd3, now settings came but wine stopped working. How can I keep both together ?

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. I fixed by downgrade libgd3:i386 package. But it seem hard to know exact version to downgrade. So I use aptitude to install gnome, then I have to choose the right solution (choose N till you get downgrade solution).

You have install aptitude first

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```